# what is the mysql host name in 1freehosting

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is a noob question.But i could not figure out the solution by any means so i am posting it here.

I have been learning php and mysql using my local machine and xampp.Now i have decided to put my works online. .So i choose one of the free hosting services like 1freehosting.I have created a mysql user like the following :

```
username : u377815502_root,
database : u377815502_login,
password : ********
```

To connect to my mysql on the webhost, i provide the following information to my php pdo connection.

```
'mysql'=>array('host'=>'localhost',
                       'username'=>'u377815502_root',
                       'password'=>'********',
                       'db'=>'u377815502_login'
                       ),
```

my question is am i doing it right?should i keep **'host'** as **'localhost'**? i am not sure!

when i try to visit my site i am getting the following error :

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'u377815502_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Check with your webhost to find out what your mysql host should be set as.

Comment: Did you try to put the ip/domain name of your remote MySQL host instead of localhost?

Comment: @PookMook my ip is 31.170.166.81. if i put that instead of local host i get a whole different error ,which is  [1130] Host '31.170.166.81' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: @frz3993 how you solved it..you may shed some light on that ..i am stuck here with it :(

Comment: Lol. I think with mysql anywhere `%` doesn't include `localhost`.

Comment: Generally `localhost` is the right setup but it all depends on how your webhost has the servers set up.

Comment: at the top of phpMyAdmin there is a  localhost>>u377815502_login
But i am not sure what it is ! u377815502_login
 is my database name

Comment: @AL-zami, how do you create the mysql username ? Does it not give you the host name ? Do you have phpmyadmin ?

Comment: i have clicked "mysql" option and filled a form for username ,database name and password field..and that's it

Comment: if i use my own ip and username and password of mysql user  i get 1130 error ..i am confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i created my own account on the host you mentioned and the host name is "mysql.1freehosting.com" without quotes obviously !! enjoy :D

Comment: i have set a password for that that username myself..it's mandatory i guess for remote server ..

Comment: why should i use localhost instead of my own ip address which 31.170.166.81 ?

Comment: oh i thought you are working on localhost , so if you are on live host they have there own server name like abc.1freehosting.com you can find the server name in your host admin area hope this helps !!!

Comment: do you mean my websites ip address which  i have mentioned in comment

Comment: i created my own account on the host you mentioned and the host name is "mysql.1freehosting.com" without quotes obviously !! enjoy :D

Comment: found it ..thanks :D

Comment: mark the answer as accepted if your problem resolved thnx!!

Comment: answer didn't solved the question ,your comment did :D... you may want to update the answer then i can accept it as an answer

Comment: haha didn't knew that, updated! :D